# How to check database in a k8s pod terminal?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

So I just graduated from a college and got a job in a company. They deploy databases on k8s which I never used before.

I wanna know how to check rows/tables in a database deployed on k8s. I asked one of my colleagues and he told me I should go to the *pod* of the database, and press *exec into pod* to enter a terminal. Then I guess I was supposed to use some commands to check the rows/tables but I have no idea how. My colleague asked me to google tutorials online but I don't even know what keywords I should type in the search bar. And I kinda can't be bothered to go through the whole document of k8s.

So could anyone tell me how to check data in this way or are there any tutorials that might help?

edited 1:

This where I reached following my colleague's instruction. What am I to do with it to check the database? It's a *mongodb* by the way.
[the page][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s77l.png

edited 2:

I managed to connect to the mongodb via the command *mongo* and a connection string. I guess I could check the database using the commands for mongo shell now. So the it's solved I think.

So I think this k8s stuff is basically just a place where u can deploy things on and manage them. I could just simply use it as any other shell.

So should I delete this question? Cuz I'm new to this community as well I'm not so sure whether people delete the questions after they were solved.

Comment: Which database and dockerfile for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find out the name of the pods and its running pods.

kubectl get pods -n your_name_space
this will return the pods. Copy the pod you want to exec into.

then exec into it using
kubectl exec -i -t pod_name -n your_namespace -- /bin/bash

Refer this:
[https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/#:~:text=If%20a%20Pod%20has%20more,to%20the%20main%2Dapp%20container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/#:%7E:text=If%20a%20Pod%20has%20more,to%20the%20main%2Dapp%20container).

After that, depending on the database you should connect to it with its client.
Example for PostgreSQL , psql is its client and you can google according to the database

Comment: There have been the pods, and I made it to the shell, but what am I to do to check the data in the database? I uploaded a screenshot in my question description, could you tell me what to do next or what should I google next? Sorry I couldn't make myself clear cause I'm not familiar with k8s at all :(

Comment: try running mongo --host localhost --port port_number